# Anyway to force domain portion of email address?

Tags: jenkins

My company's authentication service uses ids which look like email addresses (for example, "chris@security.my.com". This causes a problem when Jenkins creates the default email addresses - it tries to use "chris@security.my.com" as an email address, which fails.

I know that there's a "default user e-mail suffix" which is added to the end of a userid w/out an "@something". What I would like to do is force a specific email domain, replacing any that currently exists.

Is there anyway to do this via Groovy or some script hook I don't know about?

Comment: What security realm are you using? Can't you just register as "chris"?

Comment: @DominikGebhart All identities are "user@some.securitydomain.copy.com", so a plain 'chris' doesn't resolve to anything. Making a special version of our filter would work, but I would really like to avoid that.. effectively, all I need is the ability to run sed & then use the resulting value as email recipients.

Comment: How are you getting those usernames? LDAP? In that case, i guess the only way is to override the email by adjusting it in the user account settings.